# Has anyone had a problem with font files getting messed up with webpack url-loader? Meaning they don't look right after build

Tags: webpack, fonts, webpack-file-loader, urlloader

Fonts don't look as they should after building files, but the path is correct there's no error anywhere. Does copying them make them different? Has anyone faced similar issues

Build files and load the font families correctly to output folder

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example